# Discord.js Get server name of all servers bot is in

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

**how can i make it with array , i know this will break when the bot is in more than 100 server but i just want learn it thanks**

```js
run : async (client, message, args) => {
    guild = client.guilds.cache.forEach(server => {

        const util = [`${server.name},${server.id},${server.memberCount}`];

        const serverlist = new MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle(`Server List.`)
          .addFields(
        { name: '●Server Name        -', value: `${server.name}`, inline: true },
        { name: '●Members       -', value: `${server.memberCount}`, inline: true },
        { name: '●Server ID  ', value: `${server.id}`, inline: true }
        
        )
      
        message.lineReply(serverlist)
    
});

}
}
```

[image how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VcAp.png)

[image i expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmR1a.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i do it. ( For Guild Name )

```js
client.guilds.cache.map(g => g.name).join('\n')
```

Here how it looks in action
[image: 1st Picture Preview]

But Since **BeGo** wanted a Guild Name, Total Member, Guild ID then here's how.

```js
message.channel.send(
  { 
    embeds: [
      new MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription(
        client.guilds.cache
          .map(g => `Guild Name: ${g.name}\n  Total Members: ${g.members.cache.size}\n Guild ID: ${g.id}`).join('\n\n')
      )
    ] 
  }
)
```

[image: 2nd Code Preview]

Comment: thx for you help but i know how to do it 
but i wonted to be like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VcAp.png
name the server how many member in each server and id

Comment: my code work without problem but the bot send a new message for each server not like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VcAp.png 
i need it to be an array

Comment: @BeGo There check the edited message, i added new code like you wanted

Comment: Thank so much Alixy

Answer (score 0):

Just use a reducer.

```js
message.channel.send(client.guilds.cache.reduce((acc, srv) => acc + srv.name + '\n', "").trim());
```